# How to write multiple foreign fields from one input box?

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to know how to add multiple authors to one book using one input column.

Example:
In website i have input books and input author column. Then I have the Add button, that checks if author already exists or not, fills the many-many subtable and adds into authors and books table values if they don't exist.

My question is, how can I add and check multiple authors from one input column, like using between them coma or and, so that it would check and add multiple values if necessary.

Something like this:

```
Input: Booksname

Input: authorsname authorslastname AND authorsname authorslastname
```

So it checks and adds books and authors table and writes author_books values. AND is the thing that separates two author values to be checked and/or added.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking a UI question or a database question. Assuming you've set up your database correctly, is there a particular reason you only wish to offer one input box for author? It would be better, in my view, to have a JavaScript button to "Add a secondary author", which creates an additional input box every time it is clicked. You can then read these inputs individually, and you don't need to worry about a separator.

Comment: user interface question, Could you show me javascript buttons example that would add secondary author input box? I'll try to make something like that and if there are some problems, I'll edit it furter, like with arraystuff with new input boxes getting chained with old code..or something

Answer (score 1):

Check the function [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

You may work with something like this

```
<?php

$authos = explode(',', $_POST['authors_names'])
foreach ($authors as $author) {
    // do wherever you want with the name of author;
}
```

If you know a bit of regex your also could do like that: